Name of Pressure for real gas

Actually I was reading through the book, when I noticed this plot.
I am curious how all those isotherms pass through the same point, which leads me to wonder if there is a pressure for which the compressibility factor is same, for a given amount of gas, regardless of whatsoever the temperature is?
I've read about critical pressure, but this doesn't looks like that, right? (please confirm)

Google “Law of corresponding states.”

Sir I read about it, it involves the similarity in behaviour of diff gases according to their critical conditions. But I guess, the plot in my question is relate to the behaviour of a single gas at different temperatures @ChetMiller

Yes. But if you plot reduced pressure against reduced temperature, different gases superimpose.

@ChetMiller Yes sir...can you please cite a source..like which has image of the graphs you're saying about.

Google Law of corresponding states .

The graph from Alberty has been redrawn poorly, and the apparent single point of intersection is illusory. Here's Alberty's plot:

(Alberty doesn't state the origin of the data.)
Here's another chart of nitrogen's compressibility factor, from Yan's Introduction to Engineering Thermodynamics, with data reportedly adapted from a general compressibility factor chart for reduced temperature and pressure:

Since there isn't a common point of intersection in either case, the question's premise ("all those isotherms pass through the same point") has a problem.

Ohkkk so that book's graph is misleading. Thanks sir.

If this answer is useful, please consider upvoting it.

Ok sir done thanks
